# Как сериализовать и десериализовать json и json массив в Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d, сериализация

У меня имеется список элементов, которые присылаются c серверной стороны (присланные, к примеру, от PHP)  используя [WWW(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html). Его контент (WWW.text) выглядит так:

```
[{"playerId":"1","playerLoc":"Powai"},{"playerId":"2","playerLoc":"Andheri"},{"playerId":"3","playerLoc":"Churchgate"}]
```

Класс, который я использую выглядит так:

```
public class player {
    public string playerId { get; set; }
    public string playerLoc { get; set; }
    public string playerNick { get; set; }
}
```

Пробовал десериализовать строку разными способами:

1. Использовал `Boomlagoon.JSON`, но он почему-то извлекает только первый объект.
2. Пытался использовать `MiniJSON`: обрезал `[]` у присланной строки и затем применял библиотеку:

   ```
   IDictionary<string,object> s = Json.Deserialize(serviceData) as IDictionary<string,object>;
   foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in s) {
       Debug.Log(string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
   }
   ```

   Но оно возвращает первое значение `KeyValuePair:

   ```
   Key = playerId, Value = 1
   Key = playerLoc, Value = Powai
   ```

   А если оставить скобки, то вообще ничего не может распарсить json и поэтому логично в `foreach` кидает ошибку:

   > NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Как мне корректно сериализовать и десериализовать данные из json? Что использовать и как?

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/6104996</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Начиная с версии **5.3.3** *Unity* добавила [JsonUtility](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) в своё API. Можете забыть о различных сторонних библиотеках, разве что вы не делаете что-то очень сложное.

*JsonUtility* быстрее, чем эти сторонние библиотеки, но и, меж тем, поддерживаются только просты типы. Оно **не** поддерживает коллекции, такие как словарь (Dictionary). 
Исключением является список (List). Оно поддерживает списки (List) и массив списков (List array).

Если вам нужно сериализовать словарь (Dictionary) или сделать что-то, чем простая сериализация и десеризация простых типов — используйте сторонние библиотеки. 
В ином же случае обновитесь до версии >= **5.3.3** и попробуйте решения, которые приведены ниже.

Пример класса для сериализации:

```
[Serializable]
public class Player {

    public string playerId;
    public string playerLoc;
    public string playerNick;
}
```

**1. ОДИН ОБЪЕКТ (НЕ JSON МАССИВ)**

Исходные данные:

```
Player playerInstance = new Player();
playerInstance.playerId = "8484239823";
playerInstance.playerLoc = "Powai";
playerInstance.playerNick = "Random Nick";
```

**Сериализация 1**:

Сериализация в json с помощью метода [public static string ToJson(object obj);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html).

```
string playerToJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInstance);
Debug.Log(playerToJson);
```

*Output*:

```
{"playerId":"8484239823","playerLoc":"Powai","playerNick":"Random Nick"}
```

**Сериализация 2**:

Сериализация в json с помощью перегруженного метода [public static string ToJson(object obj, bool prettyPrint);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html). 
Добавив флаг `true` вторым аргументом в функцию `JsonUtility.ToJson` отформатирует данные. Сравните вывод ниже с выводом, что был выше.

```
string playerToJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInstance, true);
Debug.Log(playerToJson);
```

*Output*:

```
{
    "playerId": "8484239823",
    "playerLoc": "Powai",
    "playerNick": "Random Nick"
}
```

**Десериализация 1**:

Десериализация json c помощью метода [public static T FromJson(string json);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html).

```
string jsonString = "{\"playerId\":\"8484239823\",\"playerLoc\":\"Powai\",\"playerNick\":\"Random Nick\"}";
Player player = JsonUtility.FromJson<Player>(jsonString);
Debug.Log(player.playerLoc);
```

**Десериализация 2**:

Десериализация json c помощью перегруженного метода [public static object FromJson(string json, Type type);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html).

```
string jsonString = "{\"playerId\":\"8484239823\",\"playerLoc\":\"Powai\",\"playerNick\":\"Random Nick\"}";
Player player = (Player)JsonUtility.FromJson(jsonString, typeof(Player));
Debug.Log(player.playerLoc);
```

**Десериализация 3**:

Десериализация json c помощью метода [public static void FromJsonOverwrite(string json, object objectToOverwrite);](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html).

Когда используется метод `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite`, то новый экземпляр объекта не будет создан, а будет переиспользован объект, который вы передадите в качестве параметра в функцию, перезаписав его значения.

```
Player playerInstance;

void Start() {
    // создаем экземпляр объекта
    playerInstance = new Player();
    deserialize();
}

void deserialize() {
    string jsonString = "{\"playerId\":\"8484239823\",\"playerLoc\":\"Powai\",\"playerNick\":\"Random Nick\"}";    
    // Перезаписываем значения уже существующего экземпляра класса "playerInstance". Меньше затрат памяти.
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(jsonString, playerInstance);
    Debug.Log(playerInstance.playerLoc);
}
```

**2. МНОЖЕСТВО ДАННЫХ (массив json)**: ваш json содержит несколько объектов с данными.

*JsonUtility* пока в нативном виде не поддерживает массивы, но можно воспользоваться небольшим [классом-хэлпером](http://www.boxheadproductions.com.au/deserializing-top-level-arrays-in-json-with-unity/), чтобы получить **массив**, который будет работать с *JsonUtility*.

Создаем класс `JsonHelper`. Можете скопировать код хэлпера, представленного ниже:

```
public static class JsonHelper {
    public static T[] FromJson<T>(string json) {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = JsonUtility.FromJson<Wrapper<T>>(json);
        return wrapper.Items;
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array) {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper);
    }

    public static string ToJson<T>(T[] array, bool prettyPrint) {
        Wrapper<T> wrapper = new Wrapper<T>();
        wrapper.Items = array;
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(wrapper, prettyPrint);
    }

    [Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T> {
        public T[] Items;
    }
}
```

**Сериализация json массива**:

```
Player[] playerInstance = new Player[2];

playerInstance[0] = new Player();
playerInstance[0].playerId = "8484239823"; 
playerInstance[0].playerLoc = "Powai"; 
playerInstance[0].playerNick = "Random Nick";

playerInstance[1] = new Player();
playerInstance[1].playerId = "512343283"; 
playerInstance[1].playerLoc = "User2"; 
playerInstance[1].playerNick = "Rand Nick 2";

// Конвертируем в json
string playerToJson = JsonHelper.ToJson(playerInstance, true);
Debug.Log(playerToJson);
```

*Output*:

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "playerId": "8484239823",
            "playerLoc": "Powai",
            "playerNick": "Random Nick"
        },
        {
            "playerId": "512343283",
            "playerLoc": "User2",
            "playerNick": "Rand Nick 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Десериализация json массива**:

```
string jsonString = "{\r\n    \"Items\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"playerId\": \"8484239823\",\r\n            \"playerLoc\": \"Powai\",\r\n            \"playerNick\": \"Random Nick\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"playerId\": \"512343283\",\r\n            \"playerLoc\": \"User2\",\r\n            \"playerNick\": \"Rand Nick 2\"\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}";

Player[] player = JsonHelper.FromJson<Player>(jsonString);
Debug.Log(player[0].playerLoc);
Debug.Log(player[1].playerLoc);
```

*Output*:

> Powai
>
> User2

**Примечание:** если данный json массив приходит с сервера и вы не создаете его самолично вручную, то тогда надо добавить `{"Items":` в начало полученной строки и `}`  — в конец данной строки.

Вот простая функция, чтобы сделать это:

```
string fixJson(string value) {
    value = "{\"Items\":" + value + "}";
    return value;
}
```

Затем использовать её:

```
string jsonString = fixJson(yourJsonFromServer);
Player[] player = JsonHelper.FromJson<Player>(jsonString);
```

**3. ИСПРАВЛЕНИЕ ПРОБЛЕМ JsonUtility:**

*Возникают проблемы при сериализации при использовании JsonUtility.ToJson*? Получаете пустую строку или "`{}`"?

- Убедитесь, что класс не является массивом. Если это не так, то используйте класс-хэлпер выше и его метод `JsonHelper.ToJson`, вместо `JsonUtility.ToJson`.
- Не забудьте добавить атрибут `[Serializable]` сверху над объявлением класса, который вы хотите сериализовать.
- Удалите свойства из класса. Например, в переменной `public string playerId { get; set; }` **удалите** `{ get; set; }`. *Unity* не сможет сериализовать их.

*Проблемы при десериализации при использовании `JsonUtility.FromJson`?*

- Если вы получаете `Null`, то убедитесь, что json не является json массивом. Если это так, то используйте класс-хэлпер выше и его метод `JsonHelper.FromJson` вместо `JsonUtility.FromJson`.
- Если вы получаете `NullReferenceException` в процессе десериализации, то добавьте атрибут `[Serializable]` сверху над объявлением класса.

---

**Отвечая, на ваш вопрос**:

Ваши первоначальные данные:

```
 [{"playerId":"1","playerLoc":"Powai"},{"playerId":"2","playerLoc":"Andheri"},{"playerId":"3","playerLoc":"Churchgate"}]
```

**Добавьте** `{"Items":` в **начало** этой строки и **добавьте** `}`в **конец** этой строки.

Код выглядит так:

```
serviceData = "{\"Items\":" + serviceData + "}";
```

Теперь у вас есть строка:

```
 {"Items":[{"playerId":"1","playerLoc":"Powai"},{"playerId":"2","playerLoc":"Andheri"},{"playerId":"3","playerLoc":"Churchgate"}]}
```

Чтобы **сериализовать** теперь это **множество** данных из php как **массивы**, вы можете сделать так:

```
public player[] playerInstance;
playerInstance = JsonHelper.FromJson<player>(serviceData);
```

- `playerInstance[0]` — данные из первого объекта
- `playerInstance[1]` — данные из второго объекта
- `playerInstance[2]` — данные из третьего объекта

Примечание:  **Удалите** `{ get; set; }` из класса `player`. Если у вас имеются `{ get; set; }`, то работать не будет. *JsonUtility* **НЕ** работает с членами класса, которые объявлены как **свойства**.

Если они нужны, тогда придется использовать либо другие библиотеки, либо XmlSerializer/BinaryFormatter

---

<sub>Перевод ответа https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/6104996</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас проблема с пустым объектом, проверьте также, чтобы Items соответствовало в коде нужному значению

```
[Serializable]
    private class Wrapper<T> {
        public T[] Items;
    }
```

Например, мой JSON с сервера приходит вида:
{"data":[{"id":"...

Соответственно Items меняем на data.