# Как десериализовать вложенный массив JSON в Unity3d?

Tags: json, unity3d

Всем привет.
С сервера приходит json строка вида:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": {
    "a": "123",
    "b": "456",
    "c": "789"
  }
}
```

Не могу понять как правильно разобрать её в Unity.

Пользуюсь вот этой инструкцией: [Как сериализовать и десериализовать json и json массив в Unity3d?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658811/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B8-json-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B2-unity3d)

Например для такой строки:

```
{
  "message": {
    "a": "123",
    "b": "456",
    "c": "789"
  }
}
```

Подходит:

```
DataHandlerClass data = new DataHandlerClass();
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(request.downloadHandler.text, data);
```

В DataHandlerClass прописываю:

```
[Serializable]
public class DataHandlerClass
{
    public string message;
}
```

Если с сервера приходит что-то подобное:

```
{"data":[{"message":"3"},{"message":"2"}]}
```

Я использую:

```
DataHandlerClass[] data;
data = Utils.FromJson<DataHandlerClass>(request.downloadHandler.text);

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
  Debug.Log(data[i].message);
}
```

Но в первом примере приходит вложенный массив message. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как распарсить такой JSON и получить его элементы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил использованием https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

```
    // JSON
    {
      "status": 200,
      "message": {
        "a": "123",
        "b": "456",
        "c": "789"
      }
    }

    // Objects
    public class RootObj
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
        public Message message { get; set; }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
        public string c { get; set; }
    }

    // How yo use
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    RootObj rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(jsonString);
    Debug.Log(rootObj.status); // Output: 200
    Debug.Log(rootObj.message.a); // Output: 123
```